# Highmaps/Highcharts Congressional District Map Using Google Spreadsheets

Tags: jquery, highcharts, jsfiddle, highmaps

I cannot figure out for the life of me why the hc-key for congressional districts cannot or is not getting associated correctly. I've tried just about every variation of the Highmaps and Highcharts joinBy that I can. I've also looked at every answer on Stack.

We've had no problem using spreadsheets for states, but this just isn't working out for us.

I'll include the fiddle link, but here's the code. I'm even leaving in commented out code just so you can see what attempts I've made that haven't worked out for me. Also, we have to tweak the districts provided by Highmaps to update them so consider the paths if you try to duplicate it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  Highcharts.data({
    // https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z0oRIsToDT0MnlP2pfBvSN3fd-lW8nIzxTpq_fdxPDM/pubhtml
    googleSpreadsheetKey: '1Z0oRIsToDT0MnlP2pfBvSN3fd-lW8nIzxTpq_fdxPDM',
    // custom handler when the spreadsheet is parsed
    parsed: function(columns) {
      // Read the columns into the data array
      var data = [];
      function pointClick() {
        var row = this.options.row,
        district = this.district,
          incumbent = this.incumbent,
          $div = $('<div></div>')
          .dialog({
            title: function() {
              $(this).closest("span.ui-dialog-title")
                .html('<span class="state-title"></span><h2 class="state-text">' + district + ' ' + incumbent + '</h2>');
            },
            open: function() {
              $(this).closest(".ui-dialog")
                .find(".ui-button-text-only")
                .removeClass(".ui-button-text-only")
                .addClass("ui-button-icon-only")
                .html("<span class='ui-button-icon ui-icon ui-icon-closethick'></span>");
            },
            width: 740,
            height: 740
          });
        window.chart = new Highcharts.Chart($div[0], {
          credits: {
            href: 'https://www.peoplespunditdaily.com/',
            text: 'People‘s Pundit Daily'
          },
          title: {
            text: 'Election Projection Data'
          },
          subtitle: {
            text: 'Recent Election Results'
          },
          /*tooltip: {
            useHTML: true,
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:12px">{series.name}</span><hr class="style-two">',
            pointFormat: '{point.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}% to {point.challengerVote}</b>'
          },*/
          plotOptions: {
            pie: {
              dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                distance: 10,
                style: {
                  fontWeight: 'bold',
                  color: 'black'
                }
              },
              startAngle: -90,
              endAngle: 90,
              center: ['50%', '75%']
            }
          },
          series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: '2016 House Results',
            innerSize: '50%',
            data: [{
              name: 'Incumbent Vote',
              color: '#006aab',
              y: parseFloat(columns[incumbentVote][row], 10)
            }, {
              name: 'Challenger Vote',
              color: '#b02029',
              y: parseFloat(columns[challengerVote][row], 10)
            }],
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: true,
            },
            cursor: 'pointer',
            showInLegend: false,
            center: [160, 100],
            size: 120
          }, {
            type: 'pie',
            name: '2016 Presidential Vote',
            innerSize: '50%',
            data: [{
              name: 'Trump Vote Share',
              color: '#b02029',
              y: parseFloat(columns[trump][row], 10)
            }, {
              name: 'Clinton Vote Share',
              color: '#006aab',
              y: parseFloat(columns[clinton][row], 10)
            }],
            cursor: 'pointer',
            showInLegend: false,
            center: [500, 100],
            size: 120
          }, {
            type: 'pie',
            name: '2012 Presidential Vote',
            innerSize: '50%',
            data: [{
              name: 'Obama Vote Share',
              color: '#006aab',
              y: parseFloat(columns[obama][row], 10)
            }, {
              name: 'Romney Vote Share',
              color: '#b02029',
              y: parseFloat(columns[romney][row], 10)
            }],
            cursor: 'pointer',
            showInLegend: false,
            center: [160, 300],
            size: 120
          }]
        });
      }
      options = {
        chart: {
          renderTo: 'container',
          backgroundColor: null
        },
        credits: {
          enabled: false
        },
        title: {
          style: {
            textShadow: '0 0.032em 0 #999, 0px 0.15em 0.11em rgba(0,0,0,0.15), 0px 0.25em 0.021em rgba(0,0,0,0.1), 0px 0.32em 0.32em rgba(0,0,0,0.1)',
            color: '#020202'
          },
          text: '2016 House of Representatives Battleground District Map'
        },
        subtitle: {
          style: {
            color: '#1d1c1d'
          },
          text: 'Source: PPD Election Projection Model'
        },
        legend: {
          layout: 'vertical',
          align: 'right',
          navigation: {
            enabled: true
          },
          verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        },
        mapNavigation: {
          enabled: false
        },
        colorAxis: {
          dataClasses: [{
            from: -100,
            to: -75,
            color: '#006aab',
            name: 'Democrat'
          }, {
            from: -75,
            to: -50,
            color: '#6193c7',
            name: 'Likely Democrat'
          }, {
            from: -50,
            to: -25,
            color: '#9cc0e3',
            name: 'Leans Democrat'
          }, {
            from: -25,
            to: -10,
            color: '#ceeafd',
            name: 'Trump District Leans Democrat'
          }, {
            from: -10,
            to: 10,
            color: '#C39BD3',
            name: 'Battleground'
          }, {
            from: 10,
            to: 25,
            color: '#fbd0d0',
            name: 'Clinton District Leans Republican'
          }, {
            from: 25,
            to: 50,
            color: '#e99d98',
            name: 'Leans Republican'
          }, {
            from: 50,
            to: 75,
            color: '#cf635d',
            name: 'Likely Republican'
          }, {
            from: 75,
            to: 100,
            color: '#b02029',
            name: 'Republican'
          }]
        },
        tooltip: {
          useHTML: true,
          borderWidth: 2,
          backgroundColor: {
            linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 60],
            stops: [
              [0, '#F6F5F4'],
              [1, '#FFFFFF']
            ]
          },
          headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:20px">{point.district}</span><hr class="style-two">',
          pointFormat: '<span style="font-size:16px;">Rating: <b style="color:{point.color}">{point.rating}</b></span><br/><br/>',
          footerFormat: '<span style="font-size:12px">Click State for District Data</span><br/>'
        },
        series: [{
          animation: true,
          data: data,
          mapData: Highcharts.maps['maps/us-115-congress'],
          joinBy: 'hc-key',          
          states: {hover: {color: '#BADA55'}},
          point: {events: {click: pointClick}},          
          dataLabels: {enabled: false},
          cursor: 'pointer'
        }]
      };
      $.each(columns[0], function(i, key) {
        data.push({
          'hc-key': key,          
          value: parseFloat(columns[1][i]),
          district: columns[2][i],
          incumbent: columns[3][i],
          incumbentVote: columns[4][i],
          challengerVote: columns[5][i],
          trump: columns[6][i],
          clinton: columns[7][i],
          obama: columns[8][i],
          romney: columns[9][i],
          row: i
        });
      });
      // Initiate the chart 
      window.chart = new Highcharts.Map(options);
    }
  });
});
```

Here's the jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/Peoples_Pundit/fz37sar7/

Comment: Ignore the 'code' in the $.each function. I don't have code wrapped in single quotes.

Comment: Check the spreadsheet with data. The code variable (when you iterate the fetched data) does not seem to look correct - it is timestamp instead of hc-key.

Comment: Strange. When I took the column headers away it loaded the first row, but not those that followed.

Comment: Compare hc-key with the values you assign, it is "us-ca-24" against 978307200000 - it won't be matched. Moreover, I do not any kind of values that are correct in the columns (data you fetched).

Comment: I've tried to join hc-key with code, or even declare hc-key: code then joinBy hc-key alone. But it's not working. Think this is a problem with the spreadsheet itself? When I take the column headers away, it gives me the first district only.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't know exactly what I changed, but I tried one last time after adding data via the manual var = [] method.

We always add data to maps, charts and tables from Google Spreadsheets and it would have taken us forever to manually add.

I did replace "code" with "key" defined all data into their own variables. You'll notice a lot of other features, but it's the same project as above.

Here's the new updated code (Note: You need highcharts-data.js for method and highcharts-more.js for the gauge):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  Highcharts.data({
    //https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z0oRIsToDT0MnlP2pfBvSN3fd-lW8nIzxTpq_fdxPDM/pubhtm
    googleSpreadsheetKey: '1Z0oRIsToDT0MnlP2pfBvSN3fd-lW8nIzxTpq_fdxPDM',
    // custom handler when the spreadsheet is parsed
    parsed: function(columns) {
      // Read the columns into the data array
      var data = [];
      var change = {
        '-100': 'Dem',
        '-75': 'Likely',
        '-50': 'Leans',
        '-25': 'Slightly',
        '0': 'Toss',
        '25': 'Slightly',
        '50': 'Leans',
        '75': 'Likely',
        '100': 'GOP'
      };
      // Create the chart
      function pointClick() {
        // Holds var for each row, assign to = this.options row = this.options.row,
        var
          value = this.value,
          district = this.district,
          incumbent = this.incumbent,
          democratVote2016 = this.democratVote2016,
          republicanVote2016 = this.republicanVote2016,
          democratVote2018 = this.democratVote2018,
          republicanVote2018 = this.republicanVote2018,
          trump = this.trump,
          clinton = this.clinton,
          obama = this.obama,
          romney = this.romney,
          rating = this.rating,
          $div = $('<div></div>')
          .dialog({
            title: function() {
              $(this).closest("span.ui-dialog-title")
                .html('<h2 class="state-text">' + district + '</h2>');
            },
            open: function() {
              $(this).closest(".ui-dialog")
                .find(".ui-button-text-only")
                .removeClass(".ui-button-text-only")
                .addClass("ui-button-icon-only")
                .html("<span class='ui-button-icon ui-icon ui-icon-closethick'></span>");
            },
            width: 740,
            height: 740
          });
        window.chart = new Highcharts.Chart($div[0], {
          credits: {
            href: 'https://www.peoplespunditdaily.com/',
            text: 'People‘s Pundit Daily'
          },
          title: {
            text: 'Election Projection Data'
          },
          subtitle: {
            text: ''
          },
          tooltip: {
            useHTML: true,
            valueSuffix: '%',
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:12px">{series.name}</span><hr class="style-two">',
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {point.name}: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>'
          },
          plotOptions: {
            pie: {
              dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                distance: 10,
                useHTML: true,
                style: {
                  fontWeight: 'bold',
                  color: 'black'
                }
              },
              startAngle: -90,
              endAngle: 90,
              center: ['50%', '75%']
            },
            gauge: {
              dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                useHTML: true,
                format: '{point.name}'
              },
              tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {point.name}: <b>' + rating + '</b><br/>'
              },
              dial: {
                radius: '110%',
                backgroundColor: "{this.color}"
              }
            }
          },
          yAxis: {
            min: -100,
            max: 100,
            minorTickLength: 10,
            tickLength: 20,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            labels: {
              enable: true,
              useHTML: true,
              align: 'center',
              reserveSpace: false,
              rotation: 'auto',
              formatter: function() {
                var value = change[this.value];
                return value !== 'undefined' ? value : this.value;
              }
            },
            plotBands: [{
              from: -100,
              to: -75,
              color: '#006aab'
            }, {
              from: -75,
              to: -50,
              color: '#6193c7'
            }, {
              from: -50,
              to: -25,
              color: '#9cc0e3'
            }, {
              from: -25,
              to: -10,
              color: '#ceeafd'
            }, {
              from: -10,
              to: 10,
              color: '#C39BD3'
            }, {
              from: 10,
              to: 25,
              color: '#fbd0d0'
            }, {
              from: 25,
              to: 50,
              color: '#e99d98'
            }, {
              from: 50,
              to: 75,
              color: '#cf635d'
            }, {
              from: 75,
              to: 100,
              color: '#b02029'
            }]
          },
          pane: {
            startAngle: -90,
            endAngle: 90,
            center: ['50%', '90%'],
            size: 400,
            background: {
              backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#EEE',
              innerRadius: '60%',
              outerRadius: '100%',
              shape: 'arc'
            }
          },
          series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: '2016 House Results',
            innerSize: '50%',
            data: [{
              name: 'Democrat Vote',
              color: '#006aab',
              y: parseFloat([democratVote2016], 10)
            }, {
              name: 'Republican Vote',
              color: '#b02029',
              y: parseFloat([republicanVote2016], 10)
            }],
            cursor: 'pointer',
            showInLegend: false,
            center: ['25%', '20%'],
            size: 150
          }, {
            type: 'pie',
            name: '2014 House Results',
            innerSize: '50%',
            data: [{
              name: 'Democrat Vote',
              color: '#006aab',
              y: parseFloat([democratVote2018], 10)
            }, {
              name: 'Republican Vote',
              color: '#b02029',
              y: parseFloat([republicanVote2018], 10)
            }],
            cursor: 'pointer',
            showInLegend: false,
            center: ['75%', '20%'],
            size: 150
          }, {
            type: 'pie',
            name: '2016 Presidential Vote',
            innerSize: '50%',
            data: [{
              name: 'Trump Vote',
              color: '#b02029',
              y: parseFloat([trump], 10)
            }, {
              name: 'Clinton Vote',
              color: '#006aab',
              y: parseFloat([clinton], 10)
            }],
            cursor: 'pointer',
            showInLegend: false,
            center: ['25%', '45%'],
            size: 150
          }, {
            type: 'pie',
            name: '2012 Presidential Vote',
            innerSize: '50%',
            data: [{
              name: 'Obama Vote',
              color: '#006aab',
              y: parseFloat([obama], 10)
            }, {
              name: 'Romney Vote',
              color: '#b02029',
              y: parseFloat([romney], 10)
            }],
            cursor: 'pointer',
            showInLegend: false,
            center: ['75%', '45%'],
            size: 150
          }, {
            type: 'gauge',
            name: 'Election Projection',
            data: [{
              name: 'Rating',
              y: parseFloat([value], 10)
            }],
            showInLegend: false
          }]
        });
      }
      options = {
        chart: {
          renderTo: 'container',
          backgroundColor: null
        },
        credits: {
          enabled: false
        },
        title: {
          style: {
            textShadow: '0 0.032em 0 #999, 0px 0.15em 0.11em rgba(0,0,0,0.15), 0px 0.25em 0.021em rgba(0,0,0,0.1), 0px 0.32em 0.32em rgba(0,0,0,0.1)',
            color: '#020202'
          },
          text: '2016 House of Representatives Battleground District Map'
        },
        subtitle: {
          style: {
            color: '#1d1c1d'
          },
          text: 'Source: PPD Election Projection Model'
        },
        legend: {
          layout: 'vertical',
          align: 'right',
          navigation: {
            enabled: true
          },
          verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        },
        mapNavigation: {
          enabled: true
        },
        colorAxis: {
          dataClasses: [{
            from: -100,
            to: -75,
            color: '#006aab',
            name: 'Democrat'
          }, {
            from: -75,
            to: -50,
            color: '#6193c7',
            name: 'Likely Democrat'
          }, {
            from: -50,
            to: -25,
            color: '#9cc0e3',
            name: 'Leans Democrat'
          }, {
            from: -25,
            to: -10,
            color: '#ceeafd',
            name: 'Slightly Democrat'
          }, {
            from: -10,
            to: 10,
            color: '#C39BD3',
            name: 'Battleground'
          }, {
            from: 10,
            to: 25,
            color: '#fbd0d0',
            name: 'Slightly Republican'
          }, {
            from: 25,
            to: 50,
            color: '#e99d98',
            name: 'Leans Republican'
          }, {
            from: 50,
            to: 75,
            color: '#cf635d',
            name: 'Likely Republican'
          }, {
            from: 75,
            to: 100,
            color: '#b02029',
            name: 'Republican'
          }]
        },
        tooltip: {
          useHTML: true,
          borderWidth: 2,
          backgroundColor: {
            linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 60],
            stops: [
              [0, '#F6F5F4'],
              [1, '#FFFFFF']
            ]
          },
          headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:16px;"><b></b></span><hr class="style-two">',
          pointFormat: '<span style="font-size:12px;"><b>District: {point.district}</b><br/>Incumbent: {point.incumbent}<br/>Rating: <b style="color:{point.color}">{point.rating}</b></span><br/><br/>',
          footerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">Click State for District Data</span><br/>'
        },
        series: [{
          animation: true,
          data: data,
          mapData: Highcharts.maps['maps/us-115-congress'],
          joinBy: 'hc-key',          
          name: 'PPD Election Projection',
          states: {
            hover: {
              color: null,
              brightness: 0,
              borderColor: '#1d1c1d',
              borderWidth: 2
            }
          },
          point: {
            events: {
              click: pointClick
            }
          },
          cursor: 'pointer',
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: false,
            format: '{point.name}'
          }
        }]
      };
      $.each(columns[0], function(i, key) {
        data.push({
          'hc-key': key,
          value: columns[1][i],
          district: columns[2][i],
          incumbent: columns[3][i],
          democratVote2016: columns[4][i],
          republicanVote2016: columns[5][i],
          democratVote2018: columns[6][i],
          republicanVote2018: columns[7][i],
          trump: columns[8][i],
          clinton: columns[9][i],
          obama: columns[10][i],
          romney: columns[11][i],
          rating: columns[12][i],
          row: i
        });
      });
      // Initiate the chart 
      window.chart = new Highcharts.Map(options);
    }
  });
});
```

And viola! Not sure if it's faster to define and place all those variables above again, or to just pull them using:

```
y: parseFloat(columns[15][row], 10)
```

But it works and looks great.